# Angular- Material table sorting does not work properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm creating a table that should sort by data field. I followed the Angular Material documentation for this purpose but is not working, it's not showing any errors in the compiler or the browser console, the table looks like this. Event the sort header it's applied and the styles (the arrows for the sort) appear in the table the data does not sort.

```html
 <table
          *ngIf="responseObject.length !== 0"
          id="app-full-list"
          mat-table
          [dataSource]="dataSource"
          matSort
          class="qm-blocking-list__table"
          multiTemplateDataRows
        >
          <ng-container matColumnDef="unitName">
            <th
              *matHeaderCellDef
              mat-sort-header
            >
              {{ "device.list.unit.id" | translate }}
            </th>
            <td
              mat-cell
              *matCellDef="let row"
            >
              {{ row.result.unitName }}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceIP">
            <th
              *matHeaderCellDef
              mat-sort-header
            >
              {{ "device.list.device.ip" | translate }}
            </th>
            <td
              mat-cell 
              *matCellDef="let row"
            >
              {{ row.result.displayInfo?.networkInfo?.deviceIP }}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="appVersion">
            <th
              *matHeaderCellDef
              mat-sort-header
            >
              {{ "device.list.app.version" | translate }}
            </th>
            <td
              mat-cell
              *matCellDef="let row"
            >
              {{ row.result.displayInfo?.appInfo?.appVersion }}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="updateTime">
            <th
              *matHeaderCellDef
              mat-sort-header
            >
              {{ "device.list.update.time" | translate }}
            </th>
            <td
              mat-cell
              *matCellDef="let row"
            >
              {{ currentTime }}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th
              *matHeaderCellDef
              mat-sort-header
            >
              {{ "device.list.status" | translate }}
            </th>
            <td
              mat-cell
              *matCellDef="let row"
            >
              <div
                [ngClass]="{
                  'red-circle':
                    !row.result.connected || row.result.displayInfo == null,
                  'green-circle': row.result.connected
                }"
              ></div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
            <th
              *matHeaderCellDef
              mat-sort-header
            >
              {{ "device.list.action" | translate }}
            </th>
            <td
              mat-cell
              *matCellDef="let row"
            >
              <div class="qm-blocking-list__table__buttons">
                <button
                  (click)="
                    openDeviceSettingModal(
                      row,
                      row.result.unitName,
                      row.result.unitId
                    )
                  "
                >
                  <i
                    class="qm-action-btn__icon icon-edit"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  ></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr
            mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
          ></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

          <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
            <td
              *ngIf="dataSource.filter.length > 0"
              class="mat-cell"
              colspan="4"
            >
              {{ "label.no.data.matching" | translate }} "{{
                dataSource.filter
              }}"
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

and this is my ts code,

```js
export class QmDeviceListTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() id: number = 0;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'unitName',
    'deviceIP',
    'appVersion',
    'updateTime',
    'status',
    'action',
  ];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  fullAppDataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('drawer') drawer!: MatDrawer;

  private modalRef!: NgbModalRef;
  public dashboardRowCSSHeight = '100%';
  private dashboardHeight = 600;
  private dashboardRemains = 88;
  private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();
  public deviceList$!: Observable<IDevice[]>;
  public unitList$!: Observable<IUnit[]>;
  public sortedfulldeviceList!: IDevice[];
  public fulDeviceList: IDevice[] = [];
  public userDirection$!: Observable<string>;
  public isRtl!: boolean;
  public showFiller = false;
  public icon: boolean = false;
  public items = ['Device Info', 'Network Info'];
  public expandedIndex = 0;
  public index!: any;
  public expandedElement!: IDevice | null;
  public temp: any;
  public unitIdName: any;
  public unitInfoObject: any = {};
  public unitType: any;
  public unitTypeObject: any = {};
  public responseObject: IDevice[] = [];
  public currentTime: any;
  public deviceSubscription: Subscription | null = null;

  constructor(
    private unitSelectors: UnitSelectors,
    private userSelectors: UserSelectors,
    private deviceSelectors: DeviceSelectors,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    public _MatPaginatorIntl: MatPaginatorIntl,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private deviceService: DeviceService,
    private deviceDispatchers: DeviceDispatchers
  ) {
    this.userDirection$ = this.userSelectors.userDirection$;
    this.unitList$ = this.unitSelectors.unitList$;
    this.deviceList$ = this.deviceSelectors.deviceList$;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    this.deviceDispatchers.resetDeviceList();
  }

  get check() {
    return this.deviceService.isShow;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    document.title = 'Device List';

    const unitSubscription = this.unitList$.subscribe((unit: IUnit[]) => {
      if (unit && unit.length > 0) {
        this.unitTypeObject = unit.filter(
          (obj) => obj.unitType === 'DISPLAY_POINT'
        );

        let delay = 3000;
        this.unitTypeObject.forEach((unit: any) => {
          const id = unit.id;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.deviceDispatchers.getDeviceById(id);
          }, delay);
          delay += 3000;
        });

        if (!this.check) {
          this.deviceSubscription?.unsubscribe();
        }

        this.deviceSubscription = this.deviceList$.subscribe(
          (device: IDevice[]) => {
            this.responseObject = device;

            if (
              !this.deviceService.deviceLoading &&
              this.responseObject.length > 0
            ) {
              this.deviceService.deviceLoading = true;
            }

            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.responseObject);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            this.deviceService.len++;

            if (this.unitTypeObject.length == this.deviceService.len - 1) {
              this.deviceService.isShow = true;
              this.deviceService.len = 0;
            }
          }
        );
        this.subscriptions.add(this.deviceSubscription);
      } else {
        this.responseObject = [];
      }
    });
    this.subscriptions.add(unitSubscription);

    this.setRtlStyles();
  }
}
```

This is my app.module.ts file,

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QmHeaderComponent,
    QmFooterComponent,
    QmDeviceListTableComponent,
    QmBranchListComponent,
    QmMainComponent,
    QmDeviceListComponent,
    QmEditDeviceSettingsModalComponent,
    QmClearInputDirective,
    QmClearInputButtonComponent,
    QmLoaderComponent,
    QmSettingsAdminModalComponent,
    SettingsPinComponent,
    SettingsLogsComponent,
    SettingsDeviceComponent,
    SettingsAutomaticUpgradeComponent,
    SettingsUnitInfoComponent,
    SettingsCacheComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    CdkAccordionModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    NgxMatTimepickerModule,
    NgbProgressbarModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    CodeInputModule.forRoot({
      codeLength: 4,
      isCharsCode: false,
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(toastrGlobalOptions),
    ToastContainerModule,
    NgbModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...storeServices,
    TranslateService,
    GlobalErrorHandler,
    MatPaginatorIntl,
    NgbActiveModal,
    ToastService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: translateFactory,
      deps: [TranslateService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```